# Windows: Python Daemon Won't Run on IIS but Runs Locally

Tags: python, django, iis, daemon

I have a Django web application hosted on IIS. I subprocess should be consistently running alongside the web application. When I run the application locally using

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

the background task runs perfectly while the application is running. However, hosted on IIS the background task does not appear to run. How do I make the task run even when hosted on IIS?

In the manage.py file of Django I have the following code:

```
def run_background():
     return subprocess.Popen(["python", "background.py"], creationflag=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
run_background()
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

What can be done to make the background task always run even on IIS?

Comment: Don't do this. Use a proper background task manager.

Comment: Can you recommend any?

Comment: try change "background.py" to the full path "C:/something/something/background.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery is a classic option for a background task manager.

https://pypi.org/project/celery/

Alternatively, I've used a library called schedule when I wanted something a little more lightweight. Note that schedule is still in its infancy. If you need something that is going to maintain support down the line, go with celery to be safe.

https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

Without knowing the context of your project, I can't say which I would choose, but they're both good options for task management.

Comment: Can this run CONSTANTLY in the background with IIS?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use Task Scheduler to automatically start your background process when Windows starts, using an arbitrary user account.
This was the "officially suggested" solution for Celery 3 on Windows until some years ago, and I believe it can be easily adapted to run any process.
You can find a detailed explanation here:

https://www.calazan.com/windows-tip-run-applications-in-the-background-using-task-scheduler/